# Maven: How can I setup maven to run unit test and integration test separately

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, integration-testing

I have a question regarding maven.

I have got Unit Tests which have file name ending with *Test and integration test whose file name ends with *IT.

My understanding is that surefire will run the unit test and failsafe will run the integration test.

When I run: 
   mvn clean install

Both unit test and integration tests are run.

When I run:

mvn verify

Both of these tests are run too.

Is there anyway I can configure maven so that when I use: mvn clean install, only the unit tests are run. And when I use mvn verify, only integration tests are run?

My build section of POM is as follows:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>failsafe-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3-alpha-1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Since the verify phase follows the install phase, what you want in essence is to move the test goal of the surefire plugin to the verify phase. Quite a roadblock in the Maven Way :) My opinion though..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html), by convention, let's say integration tests are named as in `TestNameIT.java` and unit tests as in `TestNameUT.java`, you can use `includes` to filter integration tests or unit tests.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that is for the failsafe plugin, and will only filter tests for that plugin. It won't affect any unit tests behavior or did I miss something? Looking to solve the same issue as posted. Would like to have "mvn clean install" only run unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

## Unit- Integration- and Systemtest Setup with Maven

I have created a GitHub repository where you can see a possible Setup with maven. i post this here because i want to share my idee about this setup with others and i think this could be found when someone search about testing with maven on SO

The Repository contains a fully functional setup.

GitHub Repository: https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/maven3-unit_integration_systemtest-setup

## Features

- Maven 3.3
- Flyway for DB Migration of the Production and Systemtest Database
- Arquillian for Integration Test execution
- Mockito for Unit Testing

### Unit-Tests

- Only one Class / Business function ist tested
- No Database
- No Container
- Smallest possible unit to test
- Dependencies to other Classes are Mocked. (Mockito)
- Tests are inside *src/test* of the artifact where the unit under test class reside

### Integration-Tests

- Multiple Classes / Business functions are orchestrated and tested together
- In-Memory Database per TestCase
- EE Container. Started once for all Integration Tests
- Arquillian Remote Managed Wildfly
- Datasource Deployment per TestCase inside arquillian war (*-ds.xml)
- DB Tables are generated from JPA DDL (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop)
- Arquillian Deployments contains only the classes neede for the testcase itself
- Testdata loaded manually inside @Test or @Before method... (test data builders...)
- Tests are separated from other code

### System-Tests

- Full Wildfly deployment of the final WAR/EAR File.
- Container configuration via *.cli command line commands
- Read Database used because we need (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate)
- Database setup before deployment with maven-flyway-plugin
- Testdata loaded with sql-maven-plugin
- Tests are separated from other code